# How can I use mock in my js tests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, qunit, sinon

I try to use QUnit for testing my javascript-code.
I have simple functions:

```
function Multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
```

}

```
function CalculateBodyMassIndex(weight, height) {
    return Math.round(weight / Multiply(height, height));
```

}

```
function SummAll(array) {
    var summ = 0;
    $.each(array, function (i, el) {
       summ = summ + el;
    });
    return summ;
```

}

I have two questions:
1) How can I  verify that in function CalculateBodyMassIndex  will be called Multiply function?

2) How can I  verify that in function SummAll   will be called $.each  from jQuery library?

With thanks to waiting for an answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent post on how to use sinon.js with QUnit for mocks http://cjohansen.no/en/javascript/using_sinon_js_with_qunit.

The spies and stubs in sinon allow you to verify calls on existing objects very easily.

***EDIT***
The sinon.js documentation here http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies shows how to use Spies. Browse the full API doc for examples of stubs, mocks, etc.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer and link. I have second question. How should I write a test, if I want to make sure that function will be called with the specific parameters? Unfortunately I couldn't find example in article.

Answer (score 0):

Just paste following html and open it from your browser.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.11.0.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-1.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-qunit-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function Multiply(a, b) {
        return a * b;
      }

      function CalculateBodyMassIndex(weight, height) {
        return Math.round(weight / Multiply(height, height));
      }

      function SummAll(array) {
        var summ = 0;
        $.each(array, function (i, el) {
          summ = summ + el;
        });
        return summ;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        test('Multiply', function(){
          $.each([
            [[0, 2], 0],
            [[3, 3], 9],
            [[7, 9], 63]
          ], function(){
            var t = this.toString();
            equal(
              Multiply.apply(this, this[0]), this[1],
              t + ': Multiply ok'
            );
          });
        });

        test('CalculateBodyMassIndex', function(){
          this.spy(window, 'Multiply');
          $.each([
            [[1, 2], 0],
            [[10, 2], 3],
            [[35, 3], 4]
          ], function(i){
            var t = this.toString();
            equal(
              CalculateBodyMassIndex.apply(this, this[0]), this[1],
              t + ': CalculateBodyMassIndex ok'
            );
            ok(Multiply.calledOnce, t + ': call Multiply ok');
            deepEqual(
              Multiply.args[0], [this[0][1], this[0][1]],
              t + ': Multiply args ok'
            );
            Multiply.reset();
          });
        });

        test('SummAll', function(){
          $.each([
            [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 15],
            [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 20],
            [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 25]
          ], function(){
            var t = this.toString();
            equal(
              SummAll(this[0]), this[1],
              t + ': SummAll ok'
            );
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's easiest to take advantage of function scoping, and to allow optional arguments on your mockable functions:

```
function CalculateBodyMassIndex(weight, height, using) {
  return Math.round(weight / (using || Multiply)(height, height));
}
```

Then in your test:

```
var MockMultiplyRan = false;
var MockMultiply = function(a,b) {
    MockMultiplyRan = true;
    return Multiply(a,b);
}

CalculateBodyMassIndex(200,200, MockMultiply); // arbitrary figures
ok(MockMultiplyRan);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I am embarrassed one thing in this answer. I have to change all called CalculateBodyMassIndex in my code, haven't it? And in result I mix working logic and testing logic. I think that is wrong, because it is break solid principle. Can you explain me this moment, please?